# IIS 6 and MVC 4 bundles/static files

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, iis-6

I am trying to deploy a MVC 4 web app to an IIS 6 web server.  I can get it to server the page but it gives a 404 status code when trying to download the bundle and static js file.

With the js file that fails to download, if I type the file in by hand into the address bar, it will allow me to download the file.

I have done the following in attempts to make it work:

- `asp.net 4.0` allowed in the `Web Services Extentions`
- `c:\windows\microsoft.net\framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll` added to the  `Wildcard application maps`
- Removed and added the `BundleModule`

I still cannot get it to download the css & jquery bundle as well as a static js file.

Anyone have similar issues and found a resolution?